# NSString's initWithContentsOfFile is failing to load any file bigger than 40kb, why and what is the solution?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, initwithcontentsoffile

I want to load a file into an NSString variable and am using NSString's `initWithContentsOfFile` to do so.  However any file that is larger than 40kb the method fails and nil is returned to my variable.  Here is the code I am using:

```
NSString *fileContents;    
fileContents = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

I'm guessing it is failing due to memory shortage but surely it can handle a file as small as 40kb?!

Comment: I would advice supplying the address of an NSError pointer for the error argument, then printing out the error after calling the method. Add whatever the error is to this question.

Comment: Thank you, it might sound slightly idiotic but I was having trouble knowing how to print error's as I did not know you had to supply it with the address of an NSError pointer, I was trying to just supply it the NSError variable! Thanks a lot, due to being able to print the error I was able to correct the problem.

Comment: As I can't post my answer for another 7 hours, here it is as a comment:

After printing the error and discovering I was receiving Cocoa error code 261 I was quickly able to discover with a quick Google that my problem was that it was the NSStringEncoding argument that was causing a problem.  I changed from `NSUTF8StringEncoding` to `NSASCIIStringEncoding` and my problem is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

After printing the error and discovering I was receiving Cocoa error code 261 I was quickly able to discover with a quick Google that my problem was that it was the NSStringEncoding argument that was causing a problem. I changed from NSUTF8StringEncoding to NSASCIIStringEncoding and my problem is fixed.